# Storing entire object as json in Spring Data

Tags: spring-data

I have the following domain object:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String first;

  private String last;

  private Integer age;

  private String json;
}
```

and a `PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long>`. What I would like is to store in a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    json JSONB NOT NULL
);
```

Is there a way to override the way Spring Data reads and writes to/from the database? Ideally I'd use Jackson to convert the object to/from JSON.

Right now any operation complains that the fields on `Person` don't have a corresponding column in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) lib by [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com) - one of Hibernate authors:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can update your entity like this:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  //...
  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
  private String json;
}
```

IMO it's better to use concrete object instead of `String` here, like this:

```java
  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
  private SomeObject json;
```

More info: [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/), [2](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)