# How to read JSON String in Spring data and write to a database MySql

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-data

I have the JSON file and I want to persist it into Mysql database can anyone give me the steps to follow with the spring-data to do this, my JSON looks like this 
i created a modele with 3 class named like this
Portal.java,Spaces.java,Indicators.java

```
{
"portalName":"office360",
"spaces": [
    {
        "spaceName": "Modèle d'Espace collaboratif",
        "indicators": [
            {
                "indicatorName": "Created content",
                "indicatorCounter": "0"
            },

            {
                "indicatorName": "answers reader",
                "indicatorCounter": "0"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "spaceName": "Espace de Travail par Defaut",
        "indicators": [
            {
                "indicatorName": "Created content",
                "indicatorCounter": "0"
            },
            {
                "indicatorName": "answers reader",
                "indicatorCounter": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49837111/5380322

Answer (score 1):

If you have file wit JSON type data in it and have in Back-End three classes which should be filled with Json Data so I suggest the following:

1. use Gson library: https://github.com/google/gson
2. List item
3. Create DTO classs (consisting all three classes)
4. With file read get data from file to String:     String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("manifest.mf")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
5. Then combine Gson library, DTO class and this line: Data data = new Gson().fromJson(fileString, Data.class);

Now you will have DTO object filled with data

Comment: You dont have to you GSON or any other library, Spring has native support through JACKSON and does this behind the schenes for you.

Comment: I was not sure but I assume that Spring has JACKSON but I found Gson library more user friendly (less lines to do the job)
Then again it is a matter of preferences and maybe for new people (who are not familiar with external libraries) it is better to work with already build in.

Comment: Thats incorrect my friend. What I am trying to tell you is that you don't have to manually unmarshal anything. Spring will do it for you.

Comment: If I understood correctly Spring, by native support through JACKSON, handles this converting of Json to object?
For such purposes one option is to use `RestTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RestTemplate in Spring.

The steps are

1. If you are too lazy to create the classes that will be mapped to your json object, then you can use this website http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ it will create it for you. Lets assume that the class created is `Page.class`
2. Create a Repository class like

   ```
   import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

   @Repository
   public class OfficeRepository{

     public Page getSomething() {
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://your-url-goes-here", Page.class);
       return page;
     }
   }
   ```

This will return your JSON contents into the *Page* object created.

This was the hard part. The easy part is to save it to the DB. Please use this guide by spring https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/ in order to save it and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: In this case the class OfficeRepository will take a url that contains the JSON and return what, exactly, can you explain more to me please ??